# Restkit mapping - Works in simulator, not on iPad

Tags: ios, caching, core-data, mapping, restkit

I have been building this project for months, testing on both the simulator and the iPad with no issues like the one I'm having right now. All of a sudden, I can no longer map objects from my Rails application to Core Data upon a successful GET request ON MY IPAD. I am having no issues on the simulator.

When the app launches, I am making a large GET request if there isn't any data in Core Data. Here is what RestKit logs in the successful case (aka while using the simulator):

```
2014-09-12 17:32:38.339 SWit[44986:60b] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:150 GET 'http://10.0.0.167:3000/score/get_data'
2014-09-12 17:32:40.395 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Division' by attributes 'divisionID'
2014-09-12 17:32:40.441 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'CompetitionLocation' by attributes 'competitionLocationID'
2014-09-12 17:32:40.718 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Organization' by attributes 'organizationID'
2014-09-12 17:32:40.725 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'CompetitionGame' by attributes 'competitionGameID'
2014-09-12 17:32:40.769 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Player' by attributes 'playerID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.390 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Team' by attributes 'teamID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.457 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Conference' by attributes 'conferenceID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.489 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'StatisticInput' by attributes 'statisticInputID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.541 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Location' by attributes 'locationID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.658 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Contest' by attributes 'contestID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.693 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'League' by attributes 'leagueID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.778 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Game' by attributes 'gameID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.858 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Season' by attributes 'seasonID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.912 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Site' by attributes 'siteID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.930 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Sport' by attributes 'sportID'
2014-09-12 17:32:43.960 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Member' by attributes 'memberID'
2014-09-12 17:32:45.669 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'GameTeam' by attributes 'gameTeamID'
2014-09-12 17:32:45.770 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'CompetitionStatistic' by attributes 'competitionStatisticID'
2014-09-12 17:32:45.803 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'Competition' by attributes 'competitionID'
2014-09-12 17:32:45.848 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'User' by attributes 'userID'
2014-09-12 17:32:46.694 SWit[44986:3713] I restkit.core_data:RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.m:94 Caching instances of Entity 'CompetitionContest' by attributes 'competitionContestID'
2014-09-12 17:32:48.845 SWit[44986:6003] I restkit.network:RKObjectRequestOperation.m:220 GET 'http://10.0.0.167:3000/score/get_data' (200 OK / 7329 objects) [request=1.9976s mapping=8.5074s total=10.6074s]
2014-09-12 17:32:48.846 SWit[44986:60b] I app:GamesViewController.m:204 Load complete: Table should refresh...
```

When I try it on my iPad, RestKit logs everything through the CompetitionContest line (3rd from bottom), but then it just sits and thinks indefinitely. The core database on the iPad has 0 rows of all entities. Here is the code that initiates the GET request:

```
[self.manager 
getObjectsAtPathForRouteNamed:@"get_data"                              
object:nil                           
parameters:nil                                      
success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
{
    RKLogInfo(@"Load complete: Table should refresh...");
     [self fetchCompetitions]; //method that makes a fetch request to core data to populate self.competitions
     if (self.competitions == nil || self.competitions.count == 0)
     {
         UIAlertView *noGamesScheduled = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error!" message:@"Insert alert message here." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
         [noGamesScheduled show];
     }
     else
     {
         [self.collectionView reloadData];
     }
 }

failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    RKLogError(@"Load failed with error: %@", error);
}];
```

My mappings and everything have to be fine because it's working on the simulator just fine. What's the difference between the simulator and my iPad!?!

Comment: Are other requests working on the iPad? Simple downloads? Browser usage? Turn on trace logging (for network and mapping) and see what it says.

Comment: Wain, the problem ended up being the volume of data that RestKit was trying to GET from Rails. Right around the 6000-7000 object mark is where the iPad can't handle the request. We tested it with two iPads and both had the same issue. Any experience with this?

Comment: Not so much with response object count, though you could run into memory issues with deserialisation. How many request are you making concurrently? Why do you need so many objects on a mobile device?

Comment: We are making one large GET request when the app launches so that Core Data can get populated - we need our application to work offline and we will have several thousand objects. Any suggestions going forward?

Comment: Generally, make several smaller requests, with a max of 4 concurrent requests. You can queue the requests (RestKit natively supports this) and having multiple requests should do nothing but make the situation simpler.

Comment: Hopefully you're still willing to help me... What makes requests concurrent? Just calling them one after another? i.e. `[self.manager getObjects...]; [self.manager getObjects...]; [self.manager getObjects...]; [self.manager getObjects...];` And this will automatically queue the requests?

Comment: That will queue them, yes. You need to then get the `operationQueue` from the object manager and set `maxConcurrentOperationCount`